# Is there a way to set the display text for the value in list?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, activiti

For example, there are some business process. The user is prompted to reject or to approve some document.

Part of the workflow content model:

```
...
<constraints>
    <constraint type="LIST">
        <parameter name="allowedValues">
            <list>
                <value>Approve</value>
                <value>Reject</value>
            </list>
        </parameter>
    </constraint>
</constraints>
...
```

Instead of `Approve`/ `Reject` I want to display a different *text* (national, with spaces, etc.). But in scripts I would like to use the same `Approve`/ `Reject` values.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
<constraints>
    <constraint type="LIST">
        <parameter name="allowedValues">
            <list>
                <value>Approve|Some Approval label</value>
                <value>Reject|Some Rejection label</value>
            </list>
        </parameter>
    </constraint>
</constraints>
```

Comment: @AlekseyBykov I am getting an error while using the same constraint



 03050013 Found 1 integrity violations:
   Invalid property value: 
    Node: workspace://SpacesStore/c675df16-9625-4a01-8629-830a75b2347d
    Name: Barcode Blog.txt
    Type: {http://www.test.com/model/content/1.0}contentType
    Property: {http://www.test.com/model/content/1.0}bankDetail
    Constraint: 03050012 The value is not an allowed value: Reject