# Unable to set the list constraint property on the document

Tags: repository, alfresco, alfresco-share, content-model

This is my property and I am not able to set this on any document.
The `|` separates the value in a pair like `value and text`.

```
<property name="ipo:bankDetail">
     <type>d:text</type>
     <default>Approve</default>
     <constraints>

      <constraint type="LIST">
       <parameter name="allowedValues">
        <list>
         <value>Approve|Some Approval label</value>
         <value>Reject|Some Reject label</value>
        </list>
       </parameter>
      </constraint>
     </constraints>
    </property>
```

While setting the property on any document I am getting below error message and unable to set the property

> 03050013 Found 1 integrity violations:    Invalid property value: 
>       Node: workspace://SpacesStore/c675df16-9625-4a01-8629-830a75b2347d
>       Name: Barcode Blog.txt
>       Type: {http://www.test.com/model/content/1.0}contentType
>       Property: {http://www.test.com/model/content/1.0}bankDetail
>       Constraint: 03050012 The value is not an allowed value: Reject

I am following the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471457/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-display-text-for-the-value-in-list)

Comment: You allow the values `Approve|Some Approval label` and `Reject|Some Reject label`. `Reject` is not in this list.

Comment: Thanks, for your response.Yes, you are absolutely right.

Comment: Is there any way to allow the same if the 'Approve|Some Approval label'
is saved still I just wanted to display 'Some Approval label'?

Answer (score 1):

To display a different label you should use { }, for example `<value>active|{Some Approval label}</value>`

Otherwise, you can put you label in a message file (.properties) and use the message id, for example `<value>Approve|{label.approve}</value>`

Comment: 3060023 Found 1 integrity violations:
   Invalid property value: 
    Node: workspace://SpacesStore/5d8f2b6e-d2c7-4393-93ad-36e41c7b88d6
    Name: 1_j_AvwiEQJcyKX5S3zUglOg.jpeg
  
    Constraint: 03060022 The value is not an allowed value: Approve

Comment: Sorry But Still I am not abe to save the same.

Comment: Using your suggestion I am able to view the same <value>Approve|{Some Approval label}</value>
UI as in dropdown I can see 'Some Approval label'.
But not able to save.

Comment: As in question comment by @Lutz Horn it's true that the only Approve is not in the list so for that It may happen that alfresco can't save the unlisted values.

Comment: What you see in the option value when you inspect the UI dropdown ?

Comment: I got <option value="Approve">Some Approval label</option> from inspect element